# Use T-SQL with conditional logic to override column values for use in a SQL Server view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to take data that exists in a current view (it's been flattened) and apply some conditional logic to it on a row-by-row basis to alter it's presentation. Ideally this data could be assessed by users in a view accessed from SSMS 2012 (database in question is Microsoft SQL Server 2012). I am not a T-SQL guru or versed on many of the new features that SQL Server may offer to accomplish this. My initial thoughts were to use a cursor and some functions (I am more of a C# developer), but wasn't sure how this could be accessed via a view (main requirement). I'd rather avoid creating any new tables in the database as well (if at all possible).

Below is a sample of the current data (As-Is) along with how the users would like it displayed (To-Be). The rules that affect how the data is derived are listed below.

```
As-Is (actual source of data):

PK  MainValue   Signal1 Signal2 Signal3 Signal4 Signal5
1   12345       XYZ     12345   NULL    NULL    NULL    
2   90210       ABC     99999   90210   NULL    NULL    
3   970622      XYZ     88888   34652   970622  NULL


To-Be (how the users would like the data displayed):

PK  MainValue   Signal1 Signal2 Signal3 Signal4 Signal5
1   12345       XYZ     XYZ     XYZ     XYZ     XYZ
2   90210       ABC     99999   99999   99999   99999   
3   970622      XYZ     88888   34652   34652   34652
```

**Rules**:

- Check the `[MainValue]` field and attempt to find a match with the first `[Signal#]` field that we find (always starting at `[Signal1]` for each row of data.
- Once we get a match we look at the previous signal field (e.g. if we got a match between `[MainValue]` and `[Signal3]` we would be using `[Signal2]` as our actual source of data).
- Take this source of data and now substitute for all fields starting at where we found the match all the way to the final signal [Signal5] field.

Do this for every row. There should be only one signal field that matches and we will stop trying to make a match after we get a hit.

Comment: You forgot to post the SQL you have tried so far so that we can help you with it.

Comment: You need `UNPIVOT` your table, do the calculation,  then `PIVOT` again

Comment: i guess every column is `varchar`? otherwise you cant compare `MainValue` with `Signal1`

Comment: My apologies, I should have specified data types of the columns. Everything except the [PK] field would be a VARCHAR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to combine `nullif` with `coalesce`, like this:

```
declare @source table (PK int, MainValue varchar(6), Signal1 varchar(6), Signal2 varchar(6), Signal3 varchar(6), Signal4 varchar(6), Signal5 varchar(6))
insert into @source values
(1, '12345', 'XYZ', '12345', null, null, null),
(2, '90210', 'ABC', '99999', '90210', null, null),
(3, '970622', 'XYZ', '88888', '34652', '970622', null)

select 
    PK,
    MainValue, 
    nullif(Signal1, MainValue) as Signal1,
    coalesce(nullif(Signal2, MainValue), nullif(Signal1, MainValue)) as Signal2,
    coalesce(nullif(Signal3, MainValue), nullif(Signal2, MainValue), nullif(Signal1, MainValue)) as Signal3,
    coalesce(nullif(Signal4, MainValue), nullif(Signal3, MainValue), nullif(Signal2, MainValue), nullif(Signal1, MainValue)) as Signal4,
    coalesce(nullif(Signal5, MainValue), nullif(Signal4, MainValue), nullif(Signal3, MainValue), nullif(Signal2, MainValue), nullif(Signal1, MainValue)) as Signal5
from @source
```

---

The previous query only works if there are null values in the remaining signals after the match. If that is not the case, you will have to use this:

```
;with cte (PK, MainValue, Signal1 , Signal2, Signal3, Signal4, Signal5) as 
(
    select 
        PK,
        MainValue,
        nullif(Signal1, MainValue),
        case when nullif(Signal1, MainValue) is null then null else nullif(Signal2, MainValue) end,
        case when nullif(Signal1, MainValue) is null or nullif(Signal2, MainValue) is null then null else nullif(Signal3, MainValue) end,
        case when nullif(Signal1, MainValue) is null or nullif(Signal2, MainValue) is null or nullif(Signal3, MainValue) is null then null else nullif(Signal4, MainValue) end,
        case when nullif(Signal1, MainValue) is null or nullif(Signal2, MainValue) is null or nullif(Signal3, MainValue) is null or nullif(Signal4, MainValue) is null then null else nullif(Signal5, MainValue) end
    from @source
)
select 
    PK,
    MainValue,
    Signal1,
    coalesce(Signal2, Signal1) as Signal2,
    coalesce(Signal3, Signal2, Signal1) as Signal3,
    coalesce(Signal4, Signal3, Signal2, Signal1) as Signal4,
    coalesce(Signal5, Signal4, Signal3, Signal2, Signal1) as Signal5    
from cte
```

Comment: I think you read it wrong, the problem isnt `NULL` the issue is match MainValue with Signal and propagate that value

Comment: @Aducci--I wasn't aware of the power of COALESCE. I had a cobbled mess of a loop with a function to locate where to start "overriding" the other data. Thank you very much for your help. A quick question for you though. Let's say that each signal field has a corresponding description field (e.g. [Signal1Desc], [Signal2Desc], [Signal3Desc], [Signal4Desc], [Signal5Desc]). All the same rules apply as far as matching goes. The only wrinkle is that the description field would also override the description values in the same way that the signal field was. Do you have any ideas on how accomplish this?

Comment: @user295197 - No worries. I recommend asking another question, so it recieves  more exposure

Comment: Using a CTE I was able to meet my new requirement. I'm a little ashamed it's taken me this long to leverage them because it made the entire exercise quick and clean. The CTE allowed me to calculate where the signal matched the mainvalue and then use that in my query below to determine where to start overriding values. A few case statements and it was all done. The next challenge would be to figure out how to make it more dynamic instead of all the hard coding, but that's an exercise for another day. Thank you again for your help.